# Custom URL in apache using get parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure out how to rewrite urls using apache webserver and php.

The url below is the real nonrewritten url:

```
http://localhost:1337/rewritetest/index.php?id=12
```

And I want to reach it by

```
http://localhost:1337/rewritetest/index/12
```

My indexfile looks like this:

```
<?php 
   echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

Is this possible? The "new" url doesn't include any parameter names so I guess I have to use an order of parameters instead but I dont know how to reach them in that case.

Below is as far I've come with my rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)  
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ %1? [R=301,L]  
RewriteRule ^/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file located?

Comment: Sorry, it's located in the same folder as index.php. And it's the only htaccess on the server, and nothing configured on the serverside

Comment: Is it always supposed to rewrite to `index.php` (as your code suggests) or should it redirect to whatever basename is specified in the URL (as your URL suggests)? eg. `..../foo/26` to `..../foo.php?id=26`?

Comment: I mainly want to know how to rewrite to one file specific, but if a general solution looks kind of similiar I would be happy for such solution too. I can however work that part out myself if I get help with going in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's located in the same folder as index.php

So, given the `.htaccess` file is located at `/rewritetest/.htaccess` (as opposed to the document root ie. `/.htaccess`) then...

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
> ```

If you request a URL of the form `/rewritetest/index/12` then the above `RewriteRule` *pattern* won't actually match anything. It tries to match "index/12", but your pattern does not contain a slash so will fail. (Is the `+` inside the character class intentional?)

Try something like the following instead:

```
 RewriteRule ^(index)/(\d+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

This obviously specifically matches "index" in the URL. If you are always rewriting to `index.php` then you don't really need "index" in the URL - unless this means something different? This also assumes that the valuue of the `id` parameter consists only of digits.

To rewrite the more general `.../<controller>/26` to `.../<controller>.php?id=26` (as mentioned comments) then try something like:

```
 RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(\d+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

In per-directory `.htaccess` files the slash prefix is omitted on the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, so `/?` is not required. The above pattern also matches *something* for for the `id`, not *anything*. So, `/index/` would not match.

---

If this is a new site then the "redirect" (from `/index.php?id=12` back to `/index/12`) is not necessarily required. That's only really required if you are changing the URL structure on an existing site where old URLs already have inbound links and are indexed by search engines. In which case you could do something like the following *before* the internal rewrite:

```
RewriteBase /rewritetest/

RewriteRule %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^(index)\.php$ $1/%1 [R,L]
```

Or, for a more generic `.../<controller>/26` to `.../<controller>.php?id=26` (as above) then change the `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)\.php$ $1/%1 [R,L]
```

The additional check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is to prevent a rewrite loop after having rewritten the URL to `/index.php?id=12` earlier.